# Sphinx -- combining automodule and autoclass

Tags: python, python-sphinx

Unless I'm missing something, Sphinx's `automodule` will only document the members of a module, and not the attributes of classes defined in that module.

Is there a way *automatically* get the behavior of `automodule` and `autoclass` combined in such a way that I can automatically get documentation of a modules members *and* the attributes of any classes found in that module?

I realize I can script all this, but it gets very messy and verbose very quickly. If anyone has a neat, elegant way of doing this, I'd be happy to hear about that too.

Answer (score 2):

```
.. automodule:: whatever
    :members:
```

Comment: This will only document members of the module, as the question states.  Attributes of the member classes will remain undocumented.

Answer (score 1):

Check also [automodapi](https://github.com/astropy/sphinx-automodapi) which can help you generate API documentation for all modules automatically.